# Safecopy migration for data type renaming

Tags: haskell, migration, renaming

I'm working on the project which already have some migration history with libraries [`safecopy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy) and [`safecopy-migrate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy-migrate-0.1.0.0).
Currently the data type is

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: String
               , baz :: String
               }

deriveSafeCopy 8 'extension ''Foo

changelog ''Foo (Current 8, Past 7) [
  Added "baz" [hs|mempty|]
  ]

deriveSafeCopy 7 'base ''Foo_v7
```

I would like just to rename data type name and constructor name

```
data NewFoo = NewFoo { bar :: String
                     , baz :: String
                     }
```

all other stuff is staying the same. What should I change to perform such migration?